# Simple calculation about derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$M(s):=\{ e^s p + (1-p) \}^n$

My mathematics book says $M''(0)=np\{np+(1-p)\}.$
But my calculation is as follows.

\begin{align}
M'(s)&=n\{ e^s p + (1-p) \}^{n-1} e^s p. \\
M''(s)&=n(n-1)\{ e^s p + (1-p) \}^{n-2} e^s p +n\{ e^s p + (1-p) \}^{n-1} e^s p. \\
M''(0)
&=n(n-1)\{ e^0 p + (1-p) \}^{n-2} e^0 p +n\{ e^0 p + (1-p) \}^{n-1} e^0 p\\
&=n(n-1)p+np\\
&=n^2p.
\end{align}

Is my calculation wrong?

Comment: Isn't $M'(s)=n\{ e^s p + (1-p) \}^{n-1} (e^s p-1)$?

Comment: @Masoud : no, $M'$ is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your calculation of the second derivative $M^{''}(s)$, you forgot a factor of $e^sp$ in your first term. So you should have $$M''(s)=n(n-1)\{ e^s p + (1-p) \}^{n-2} e^{2s} p^2 +n\{ e^s p + (1-p) \}^{n-1} e^s p$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Whithout doing any calculation it is self evident that the result of your book is correct!

In fact $M(s)$ is the moment generating function of a binomial distribution with second moment

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=np(1-p)+n^2p^2$$

that is exactly the second derivative in $s=0$

---

Anyway the first derivative is correct.

The second one is

$$M''(s)=np\{e^s[e^sp+(1-p)]^{n-1}+e^s(n-1)[e^sp+(1-p)]^{n-2}e^sp\}_{s=0}=$$

$$=np\{[p+(1-p)]^{n-1}+(n-1)p[p+(1-p)]^{n-2}\}=np[1+np-p]=np[np+(1-p)]$$

Comment: My calculation was wrong. Thank you.